Java: How to listen on a port without "binding" to the port
I'm running KDE Plasma 6 (Wayland) on an Arch Linux rig I want to connect to remotely, but currently the KRDP program is in alpha and cannot accept connections without clicking "accept" on the desktop.
I don't know C++ and therefore cannot contribute to the project, but I tried to work around this using my limited Java knowledge to listen for an RDP connection on port 3389 and then use a robot object to move the mouse to and click on the accept button to allow my connection.
It works perfectly fine when testing on my Windows rig, but my Linux machine won't allow both the Java program and KRDP to use the port at the same time, it gives me an IOException. On the windows machine I get no error and it works flawlessly.
here's the code itself
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{
        //to ensure the program is actually running
        System.out.println("its working!");
        final int port = 3389;
        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {
            try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port)) {
                //checks for a connection on the port, will repeat on failure
                listener.accept();
                run = false;
                done();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to bind to port");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void done() throws AWTException{
        final int xVal = 1100;
        final int yVal = 550;
        Robot mcp = new Robot();
        mcp.mouseMove(xVal, yVal);
        mcp.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    }

}

I tried running the program first and the RDP server second, the program ran successfully but the RDP server couldn't listen on the port and gave repeated errors, I assume this is because the listener object is eating up the port. How can I look on that port without preventing it by being used by rdp?

That is not something that can be done. Use two ports.

How would I do this? I need to be listening on the same port the RDP connection is incoming from

RDP to 3389. Telnet to 3390. Use 3390 to click accept for 3389. or use a real operating system.

Why do you need to listen to the same port the RDP connection is incoming from? If that really is the case then you need to setup a proxy service that binds to that port and relays according to your needs.
